# dropping ticklabel on pgfplot axis

Tags: pgfplots

I've just started to play with pgfplot. I'm trying to prepare a plot like to following

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,  axis x line=middle, axis y
line=middle, xlabel=$k$, ylabel=$\omega$, ymin=0,xmin=-2,ymax=60]
\addplot[blue,domain=0:5, line width=1.5pt] {x^2+25};
\addplot[orange,domain=0:5,line width=1pt]{3*x+22.75};
\addplot[cyan,domain=0:1.5, line width=1pt,dashed]{18.166*x};
\node[coordinate,pin=right:{$v_{\phi}=\frac{\omega}{k}$}]
    at (axis cs:1,17) {};
\node[coordinate,pin=right:{$v_{g}=\frac{d\omega}{dk}$}]
    at (axis cs:2.5,30) {};
\node[coordinate,pin=left:{dispersion relation}]
    at (axis cs:4.5,47) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Wave dispersion relation with phase and group velocity}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
```

What I would like to do is dropping the x-y tick labels so that we just maintaing the x-y title. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `xtick` and `ytick` to `\empty`, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  minor tick num=1,
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=middle,
  xlabel=$k$,
  ylabel=$\omega$,
  ymin=0,xmin=-2,ymax=60,
  xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty]
\addplot[blue,domain=0:5, line width=1.5pt] {x^2+25};
\addplot[orange,domain=0:5,line width=1pt]{3*x+22.75};
\addplot[cyan,domain=0:1.5, line width=1pt,dashed]{18.166*x};
\node[coordinate,pin=right:{$v_{\phi}=\frac{\omega}{k}$}]
    at (axis cs:1,17) {};
\node[coordinate,pin=right:{$v_{g}=\frac{d\omega}{dk}$}]
    at (axis cs:2.5,30) {};
\node[coordinate,pin=left:{dispersion relation}]
    at (axis cs:4.5,47) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: @NicolaVianello You're welcome. By the way, this is mentioned in the manual in section 4.14 Tick options, on page 216.